# TYPO3 6.2 extbase repository object cloning not saving records properly

Tags: php, repository, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I've an event creating extension which contains an option to create events for the users. This is implemented using extbase repository method. In the event creation form I've a start date, end date and weekdays which the events should be repeated.

For example if I set start date as 13-10-2015 and end date as 30-10-2015. And selected the weekday as "Wednesday".So the event will repeated in all "Wednesdays" between 13 and 30.

When I create a non-repeated event, it will work properly. But for the recurring event, I've implemented the cloning method of extbase repository.

```
if (!empty($endDateRecurring) && !empty($recurringWeekDays)) {
            $endDate = new \DateTime($endDateRecurring);
            $startDate = $newEvent->getDate();
            $startDate->setTime(0, 0);
            $datetimeDiff = $startDate->diff($endDate);

            for ( $event=1; $event <= $datetimeDiff->days; $event++ ) { 
                $checkDate = $newEvent->getDate()->add(new \DateInterval('P'.$event.'D'));
                $dayOfWeekNo = date('w',$checkDate->getTimestamp());

                if ( in_array( $dayOfWeekNo, $recurringWeekDays ) ) {               
                    $eventProperties = \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Reflection\ObjectAccess::getGettableProperties( $newEvent );
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Reflection\ObjectAccess::setProperty( $eventProperties, 'date', $eventProperties['date']->add(new \DateInterval('P1D') ) );

                    $eventCopy = $this->objectManager->create('\TYPO3\EventCreate\Domain\Model\Event');                 
                    foreach ( $eventProperties as $propertyName => $propertyValue ) {
                        if (\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Reflection\ObjectAccess::isPropertySettable($eventCopy,
                            $propertyName) && !in_array($propertyName, array('uid','pid'))) {
                                $propertyValue = \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Reflection\ObjectAccess::getProperty( $newEvent, $propertyName );
                                \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Reflection\ObjectAccess::setProperty( $eventCopy, $propertyName, $propertyValue );
                            }
                    }
                    //TODO: cloning doesn't work because the id is already set and it thus doesn't add a new object to the repository.
                    //either create a new object and copy all content properties, or find another way to add more events to the db for recurring days.
                    $this->eventRepository->add($eventCopy);
                    $this->objectManger->get('Tx_Extbase_Persistence_Manager')->persistAll();
                }
            }
        }
```

Here $recurringWeekDays is an array which contains selected repeated weekday id ( For Monday-1, Tuesday-2 like this ).

Issue is when there is any number of days to be inserted, then only one record inserted to the database. In the above example 3 Wednesdays between 13th and 30th October. But only one record inserted.

If anybody knows the solution, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that using the objectManager is the problem. Try to change

```
$eventCopy = $this->objectManager->create('\TYPO3\EventCreate\Domain\Model\Event');
```

in

```
$eventCopy = new \TYPO3\EventCreate\Domain\Model\Event();
```

Does that work?

Comment: Sorry Jay. It is not working...:( . I think the problem is with *$this->objectManger->get('Tx_Extbase_Persistence_Manager')->persistAll();*. Can you please give me a hint about this?

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. `persistAll()` just forces the repository to persist all changes (e.g add, updated or removed object) on the database. Otherwise this will only be done after your Controller-Action is finished. Therefore it should be enough to run persistAll() right after your `for`-loop is finished.

Comment: Can you investigate your `$eventCopy` right before you call `add()` with
`\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::devLog('uid: '.$eventCopy->getUid().', isDirty? '.($this->_isDirty() ? 'yes' : 'no'), 'myextensionkey');` The uid should be null and the object marked as dirty, but is it the case?
Another question: Why do you remove the pid-property?

Comment: Actually I don't need to remove the pid. I just added this in my development. My problem is suppose if there are 4 entries, then the last entry inserted to the database 4 times ( number of loop executed ).

Comment: the objects have an internal ID and this is used in the ORM to insert a record into the database. If you do not reset this ID, then extbase will threat all objects as identical. You will need to set ``_isDirty`` and also check ``_memorizeCleanState()`` (see ``ObjectMonitoringInterface``). From ``DomainObjectInterface`` check ``_isNew``. Full reference: http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_domain_object_1_1_abstract_domain_object.html

Comment: Aha, good hint! But after taking a deeper look into Extbase's code, I wonder if changing `_isDirty` and the others will really be the solution. But the comment-section is too short to explain it here. I'll do it in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just another try as a conclusion from the discussion from my earlier answer:

As @pgame pointed out, the problem is the internal ID used in the ORM. In `Persistence/ObjectStorage.php` I can see that PHP's `spl_object_hash($object)` is used to generate the internal ID for a object in the storage. So we have to make sure that this function does not produce the same hash more than once.

As it is written in http://php.net/manual/de/function.spl-object-hash.php, you can read in the first user note that this function does not generate its hash by the object properties but by internal handles to guarantee that multiple instances in memory will have different hashes. But once an instance is destroyed the Hash **may be reused** for anonther instance.

Hence we have to make sure that in each for-iteration the instance of `$eventCopy` will not be overwritten (and thus destroyed) by the next instance for it may result the same hash in the ObjectStorage. I'd suggest to create an array `$eventCopies` and push every new instance of `$eventCopy` to this. So every instance will be kept alive in this array through all iterations in your for-loop. After all, you can loop again over your `$eventCopies` and add each to your repository.

Does it work this time?

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I'll try this.

Comment: Hmm, I thought about my explanation here. I forgot that the ObjectStorage will keep a reference to the Object in memory, so it should not be destroyed when `$eventCopy` is overwritten. ... Therefore my solution here should still not fix the problem. Or does it? ... Dude, I'm fixated on finding a solution to your problem now.